# Create a div that appears after scroll, stays permanently at bottom of page

Tags: sticky-footer

I am trying to create a 'back to top' image, it needs to stick to the bottom right corner of the page.

I have created the div with the image but I do not know what is the best way to make it permanently stay at the bottom of the page. Is it best to use absolute positioning?

Also, I want the div to only appear when the user has scrolled past a certain point, and to fade in (or something similar?)

I have looked online but can't find anything that does what I want. I tried simply getting the div to stick to the bottom but the tutorials I have been using show how to create footers, rather than just one small graphic, so it doesn't work as well.

What are the best practices for this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want that the div should be at the right hand side and at the bottom?

Comment: Yes I want the div to be at the bottom right hand side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRN64/1

HTML

```
<div id="log" style='display:none; position:fixed; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:200px background-color:red;'>Back To Top</div>

<div style='height:1200px; background-color:orange'>Try Scrolling me</div>​
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {              
      $('#log').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
    });
})
​
```

To fade:

Change: `$('#log').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);` to

```
$(document).scrollTop() > 100 ? $('#log:hidden').fadeIn() : $('#log:visible').fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer :) It works perfectly. Do you have any advance on the kind of JS terminology I might search for a solution to make it 'fade' in (or appear in a nicer way) so that I may search for a solution on Google?

Comment: I would search for fade in :). Or, you can see my edited answer that shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks very much :) Another question, when the page loads the back-top-top link is there regardless, and then disappears when you scroll (before reappearing when you get past the certain point). Is there a way to not make it show then? I only want it there when the scroll is past 120px. Live site is: www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite

Comment: I don't see the functionality as said in the demo. Can you please check ...?

Comment: Is there a way to switch out the pixel value for a percentage of the screen? I'm trying to get it to fade in just before you reach the bottom of the page (so like 98%). Solid solution tho!!

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a div

```
<div class="bottom">Your Img</div>
```

Apply `fixed position` to the `div` as we want the div to appear fixed.

By doing so we can freely move the `div` to our desired area.

Then by applying `CSS` property `right:0;` and `bottom:0;` we can move the `div` to the right most and the bottom most position on the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bottom
{
width:100px;
height:30px;
background-color:Gray;
border:1px solid black;
position:fixed;
right:0; 
bottom:0;    
}​
```

Here is a **[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VCbHg/1/)**

Comment: This is perfect thank you :D Sorry I just couldn't get my head around it. Any ideas how to make this display only after a certain scroll on the page?

Comment: @Francesca Check out aquinas answer , he provides the scrolling part.If you find my answer helpful please upvote it.Thanks.